# Issue with encrypting password

Tags: php, mysql

I have this issue with password encryption, now, I use md5.. i know it's not the safest but anyways.

I have this code:

```
$import="INSERT into users(Username,Password,Email,first_name,last_name,phone,user_id) values('$data[0]','md5($data[1]).','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]')";
```

Now, this posts in the database the value like it is: I mean i.e

> md5(A101)

How can I solve this?

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***.  Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function isn't a variable, sop it can't be parsed inside double quotes:

```
$import="
    INSERT into users
    (Username,Password,Email,first_name,last_name,phone,user_id) 
    values('$data[0]','".md5($data[1])."','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]')";
```

While PHP parses variables inside double quotes, it won't look for every function possible. You will need to break the string and concat the values in using the `.` concat function.

Comment: blah ... i'm starting to hate you ++ :)

Comment: How am i supposed to solve this please? it's because, i use it to insert a csv file..

Comment: @blerta I gave you the insert query in the answer mate. It will work fine if you break the string, concat and run the query as it is :)

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 2):

```
$import="INSERT into users(Username,Password,Email,first_name,last_name,phone,user_id) 
       values('$data[0]','".md5($data[1])."','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]')";
```

this should work.

You can't do something like this `$str = "$str1";` with function calls, so you must do something like this:  `$str = "'" . md5($str1) . "'"`

Answer (score 1):

you cannot call functions like that:

```
$import="INSERT into users(Username,Password,Email,first_name,last_name,phone,user_id) values('$data[0]','".md5($data[1])."','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]')";
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain PHP do you think `echo "md5($data[1]).";` would call the function? Of course not, it's part of the string.

You need to concatenate the md5 call:

```
"blah blah blah".md5($data[1])."more blah";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual issue is that you've placed a function call into a string, you can simply concatenate the return value of `md5` into your string like this:

```
'" . md5($data[1]) . "'
```

That said, please don't write inserts like this, it's dangerous if `$data` contains user input.

You're almost **always** better off using prepared statements to insert data into a database. I'd highly recommend that you take up reading about PDO/MySQLi, or at the very least if you're not using it already, `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0):

For one, using arrays within a string will not work. You need to end the string and concatinate the array elements to have their value in it. The same goes for functions such as the md5() functions.

Try:

```
$import="INSERT into users(Username,Password,Email,first_name,last_name,phone,user_id) values('".$data[0]."','".md5($data[1])."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."','".$data[4]."','".$data[5]."','".$data[6]."')";
```

I hope this helps.